# Parse single quotes in JSON using Ansible

Tags: json, ansible, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to run an Ansible playbook which has an input of JSON with single quotes in it. Playbook run fails with the below error. Is there any way I can parse through the single quotes. As of now I am getting below error.

```
JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'

ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'

The error appears to be in line 161, column 69, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

            "logGroups": "aws_log_group_name",
            "query": "fields @timestamp, @message | parse @message 'GET *:4' as apiName | parse @message ':443* H' as backend | sort @timestamp desc | stats count() as count by backend | sort count desc"
                                                                    ^ here
```

JSON:

```
{
    "type": "custom",
    "width": 24,
    "height": 18,
    "properties": {
        "params": {
            "region": "us-east-1",
            "logGroups": "aws_log_group",
            "query": "fields @timestamp, @message | parse @message 'GET *:4' as apiName | parse @message ':443* H' as backend | sort @timestamp desc | stats count() as count by backend | sort count desc"
        },
        "updateOn": {
            "refresh": true,
            "timeRange": true
        },
        "title": "ELB logs"
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide the code. [edit] the question and make it [mre].

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ and asked to close.

Comment: The JSON you posted looks valid, but the JSON in the error message looks weird. Those backslashes make it invalid, and it’s especially odd that half the backslashes appear _after_ the apostrophes.

Answer (score 1):

It's valid [JSON](https://jsonlint.com/)

```yaml
shell> cat dashboard.json 
{
    "type": "custom",
    "width": 24,
    "height": 18,
    "properties": {
        "params": {
            "region": "us-east-1",
            "logGroups": "aws_log_group",
            "query": "fields @timestamp, @message | parse @message 'GET *:4' as apiName | parse @message ':443* H' as backend | sort @timestamp desc | stats count() as count by backend | sort count desc"
        },
        "updateOn": {
            "refresh": true,
            "timeRange": true
        },
        "title": "ELB logs"
    }
}
```

and the playbook below works as expected

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: dashboard.json
        name: dashboard
    - debug:
        var: dashboard
```